# Print only the contents after a certain pattern match

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a string like this:

```
query:schema:query_result{cell=ab}: <timestamp>
```

I'd like to just print the ab and assign it to a variable. How can I do this with grep/sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try his,

```
$ var=$(grep -oP '=\K\w+' <<< "$str")
```

or

```
$ sed 's/.*=\(\w\+\).*/\1/' <<<"$var"
ab
```

Comment: How would I modify it if there was more stuff inside the {}, like {country=us,city=chicago,cell=ab}

Comment: $ cmd="query:schema:query_result{country=us, city=chi, cell=ab}: <timestamp>"
$var=$(grep -oP '=\K\w+' <<< "$cmd")
var is now "us chi ab". How do I just assign it to ab?

Comment: try this `var=$(grep -oP '\{[^}]*=\K\w+' <<< "$str")`, https://regex101.com/r/bG9bZ9/1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use awk:

```
s='query:schema:query_result{cell=ab}: <timestamp>'
awk -F '[=}]' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
ab
```

To assign it to a variable:

```
var="$(awk -F '[=}]' '{print $2}' <<< "$s")"
```